# objective-c: Extremely Strange and annoying string problem

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsuserdefaults, nsmutablestring

i've been working on a tableview program and i have a function that processes several data from user preferences, and core-data. the program parses these things and returns a url adress. heres the code:

```
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *serverAdress = [prefs stringForKey:@"serverAdress"];
 serverAdress = [serverAdress stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"];

 NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

 NSString *dateTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",dateString,[dashboardParameters attribute1]];

 NSTimeInterval dayInterval = [[dashboardParameters attribute2] intValue]*60*60*(-1);
 NSDate *date2 = [[dateFormatter2 dateFromString:dateTimeString] addTimeInterval:dayInterval];
 NSString *urlString = 
 [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@/webservices/service1.asmx/getHourlySales2?tarih2=%@&tarih1=%@&salesType=%@",
  serverAdress,
  dateTimeString,
  [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:date2],
  [dashboardParameters itemOrder]
  ];
 urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"]; 
 return urlString;
```

Everything works great, i have no problem on retrieving data. But when i execute the code, i get this log output:

> //server.dyndns.org/webservices/service1.asmx/getHourlySales2?tarih2=20.01.2011%2016:00&tarih1=19.01.2011%2016:00&salesType=Hepsi/webservices/service1.asmx/getHourlySales2?tarih2=21.01.2011%2022:00&tarih1=21.01.2011%2011:00&salesType=Hepsi

it has to be

> //server.dyndns.org/webservices/service1.asmx/getHourlySales2?tarih2=20.01.2011%2016:00&tarih1=19.01.2011%2016:00&salesType=Hepsi

But strangely the program adds

> /webservices/service1.asmx/getHourlySales2?tarih2=21.01.2011%2022:00&tarih1=21.01.2011%2011:00&salesType=Hepsi

by itself after the normal processing.

Also another important thing, the code runs normally when i remove

`NSString *serverAdress = [prefs stringForKey:@"serverAdress"]` from the code and enter serveradress manually.

Plase help , everything in the program works fine but im stuck with this problem.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you checked wether `[prefs stringForKey:@"serverAdress"]` gives you what you are expecting?

Comment: Try putting an `NSLog` for serverAdress and see what it gives you. Will the server address be changing somewhere in your program?  If not, I'd just hardcode it as a string instead of messing with `NSUserDefaults`.  Oh and by the way, it doesn't matter a smidgeon, but you might want to spell it `serverAddress`. :)

Comment: LOL Problem solved [prefs stringForKey:@"serverAdress"] was set to wrong value. i cant belive i've missed this!

Comment: lol i'm changing to serveraddress :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's in serverAdress *before* you add it to urlString. Looks as if serverAdress contains '//server.dyndns.org/webservices/service1.asmx/getHourlySales2?tarih2=20.01.2011%2016:00&tarih1=19.01.2011%2016:00&salesType=Hepsi'

Comment: Thanx for helping, looks like [prefs stringForKey:@"serverAdress"] was set to wrong value. looks like i am a little bit too tired to NSLog the serverAdress value.